# Custom notification based on time and day in android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to generate notification every day but multiple times . The times are predefined. I have seen some example that generate a notification once for a particular time and date. But what i want is to generate a notification whenever the time matches a set of timings.

for example on monday i want to generate a notification at 10 , 11 , 12 ,1:30 , 3:00 and so on.

Please suggest a way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do here is you can create one `Service` for that and in that you can put conditions to generate notification on what time you want to generate notification.

Comment: Thanks Anil :) I finally figured out . I am using an alarm manager to call the service regularly and in the service i am using the conditions like you mentioned.